# SQL - trigger only works after second statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger that needs to check if a book date is not after the incheck date. But when I execute a statement with the book date after the incheck date (to check if my trigger works) it does nothing. When I do the statement a second time the trigger works, probably because then there is a row that triggers the trigger. But what I don't understand is why the trigger does not work when I do a 'wrong' statement the first time

This is the trigger and the statement that should trigger the trigger.

```
create trigger t_check_date
on booking
after update, insert
as
if exists
(
select b.bookid
from booking b
join bookingroom bk
on b.bookid = bk.bookid
where b.bookdate >= bk.incheckdate
)
begin
    raiserror('Error',16,1)
    rollback transaction
end
```

Here the statements, first the atributes then the values.

```
insert into booking values (bookdate, count_person, hotelid, rating, customerid, employeeid )
insert into booking values ('2019-05-17', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 )
insert into bookingroom values (roomnumber, incheckdate, chechoutdate)

insert into bookgingroom values (4, '2018-06-01','2019-08-02')
```

So when I execute the statements once the trigger does nothing but the second time it does.

Comment: @DanB SQL server

Comment: Your trigger need a row in bookingRoom (because of join).  Is your issue is due insert order?

Comment: @DanB No, insert order is fine because of the foreing key (bookingid) that 'boekingkamer' needs.

Comment: Yes, but how the query can check if there are no entry in bookingroom?  The `if exists(...)` return no record.

Comment: Your insert statement doesn't include `bookid` column.  Please post working query.

Comment: @DanB I think that is the right way of thinking. What do you suggest?

Comment: @DanB Correct because I those colums are IDENTIY colums so no bookid necessary

Comment: Then, I would suggest to write a stored procedure that take all parameters, does the validation, and if everything OK write to the 2 tables.

Comment: You insert a record into `booking`. There is not a matching record in `bookingroom`. So you get no trigger fire. Then you insert a record into `bookingroom`. It would match, but the trigger is on `booking` and not `bookingroom`, so no fire. On the second call, you insert another record into `booking`. Now there is a match, and the trigger fires and rolls back the transaction. Then you insert another record into `bookingroom`. Again, there is a match, but no trigger to fire.

Comment: @Shawn that is it! So what do you suggest? I already have tried the same trigger om bookingroom but if the  bookdate is after the incheckdate the insert for booking gets executed and de insert for bookingroom not.

Comment: What exactly is your workflow here? I'm guessing that someone would first have a booking. Then they would checkin to the room for that booking. Then it would be ok for them to create another booking, but wouldn't be able to create a third booking without checking in to the second one. Is it possible to have multiple room checkins on one booking? I think you might be better off to just skip the trigger and not allow someone to checkin if there isn't an earlier booking.

Comment: And if they can't have more than one active booking, create a constraint that prevents that.

Comment: It's usually easier to not allow someone to do something than it is to let them do it and then check if they were supposed to.

Comment: @Shawn The workflow is: An employee makes a booking for a guest and that goes into `booking`. So the guest needs to stay in a room that has to claimt for the time he stays. `incheckdate` and `checkoutdate`.

Comment: So a guest can not have more than one open booking at a time?

Comment: Regardless, a `booking` and a `bookingroom` seem to entail two different events. So they shouldn't be part of the same transaction to roll back. Again, rather than a trigger, I'd simply not allow a checkin without an applicable booking. That's much easier than trying to fire a trigger to check.

Comment: @Shawn Yes a guest can.

Comment: How can I make them part of the same rollback?

Comment: Why would you want to? They represent two different things.

Comment: And I'm still not sure they should be different tables. I don't know your schema, so I can't tell. But it would seem like it could be handled in just one table, where a booking date also has a related room with blank checkin/out dates until those are completed. Unless one booking can contain multiple rooms.

Comment: Yes but bookingroom has a foreign key from booking ad since I have Identity colum ON I want a rollback on the whole transaction. Otherwhise I get FK issues.

Comment: So if someone doesn't stay in a room you want to delete their original booking also? What kind of FK issues do you get? If `bookingroom` has a FK for `booking`, then it shouldn't matter if you delete the `bookingroom` record. At the worst, you would end up with a `booking` that doesn't have a related record in `bookingroom`. Can you use http://dbfiddle.uk/ to set up a simple example of schema and data?